# IBM Watson Assitant: How to obtain a full address

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am working on making a reservation tab as follows:

- Date of the pick up:   **@sys-date**
- Time of the pick up:   **@sys-time**
- Address of the pick up: **@sys-location**

The problem is that Watson Assistant doesn't recognize the location on live test when customer input detail of their location. It keeps asking me what's the address?

All I get is date of the pick up and time with no pick up address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [system entity @sys-location in Watson Assistant](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-system-entities#system-entities-sys-location) should be used with caution. It is a BETA feature for some languages and only with this capability:

> The @sys-location system entity extracts place names (country, state/province, city, town, etc.) from the user's input. The value of the entity is not a system-standard value of the location.

My suggestion is to ask for the address and capture it as an entire string. Then, try to standardize the input to your local address format, e.g., by using an address verification system.

Another option is to break up the address into parts like city, street, zip code and more. Depending on the country there are different formats and even more than one format to specify it. "What is your city?", "What is your street address?", ...

Comment: Can you give me some examples

Comment: I added more details on the address verification system and individual questions.